# Android ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: android

These are my two classes and my manifest. I got a `ClassNotFoundException`. I have also included my log cat.

My first class:

```
  package com.m.mech;

    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseACL;

    import com.parse.ParseUser;

    import android.app.Application;

    public class ParsePro extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this,"tadjgdfghdfgdfdfcfgdfcr",      "QlwkikEQCXZ8cW9ghjwbFpXjAaWEr5Js6H2Cud5");


        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }

}
```

My second class:

```
package com.m.mech;

import com.m.mech.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
}
}
```

My manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.m.mech"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application

    android:name="com.m.mech.ParsePro"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.mech.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

My LogCat:

```
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.m.mech/com.parse.mech.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.m.mech-2.apk
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.m.mech-2.apk
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
10-15 14:59:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     ... 11 more
10-15 14:59:47.998: E/Trace(1137): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Why am I getting this `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: your package name is package com.m.mech;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your manifest does not match your package/classname of your main activity:

```
android:name="com.parse.mech.MainActivity"
```

Change it to

```
android:name="com.m.mech.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 1):

use right package name for registering service and Activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` because package name is `com.m.mech` but you are currently using `com.parse` for registering.

```
....
<activity
    android:name="com.m.mech.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service android:name="com.m.mech.PushService" />

<receiver android:name="com.m.mech.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

your main activity is in package `com.m.mech` but in your manifest file you put `com.parse.mech.MainActivity` as start point

Answer (score 0):

whow.. 
if your packagename is correct, just clean the project and export it again..
It's worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

**For Android Studio**
Even if after changing the package name in the manifest file is not working for you, just try to invalidate cache and reload the project. It worked for me.

All the files were correct for me but still there was this error. I just created classes using default templates in Android Studio

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate Cache and Restart (DIalog box)
```

**For Eclipse**
Clean the project and reload it again.

Comment: This worked for me, don't know why it was down voted

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the Theme!